# igraph edge thickness and weight

Tags: r, igraph

I have data which show vaccine developers, buyers and doses/capita(I adjusted as weight). How can I define vaccine developers and buyers as nodes and doses weight as edge. Also how can I manipulate thickness of edges according to weight. I am new at Igraph so thank you for your help.

Dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iJRLXBKTKhvVzX0lMsWngkHYQ263AxdY/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edge.width` within `plot`, e.g.,

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(g,edge.width = E(g)$Weight)
```

Comment: thank you but I think this is for python, I need to use r studio for my project.